# forcing breaks in gigantic footnotes

Tags: footnotes, page-breaking, bigfoot

I have huge footnotes with linguistic examples in them.

[image]

For some reason xelatex (texlive 2015) decides to put everything onto the next page and leave a huge hole. I was reading around and found the `\interfootnotelinepenalty` may help. I played with it, setting the area in which the footnotes occur in curly bracket including `\interfootnotelinepenalty=10`. But this did not have any effect. I also found the `bigfoot` package and this works. It places the footnotes onto the desired page. But it has side effects. The example numbers are sticking out:

[image]

Now question: Is there an easy way to reach the effect of `bigfoot` without breaking other things?

Comment: Without an example it is difficult to say. Beside this: Imho such footnotes horrible.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I agree, but in some disciplines of science this is the recommended way -- having a footnote region larger than the textheight

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- The demands of the genre, the requirements of the citation style, and the needs and expectations of the audience sometimes determine the size of the footnotes. It is not always up to the author in the same way the citation style is imposed by someone other than the author him- or herself.  But an MWE is needed here.

Comment: @jon It is not relevant *why* the author uses such large footnotes. They are horrible regardless if he does it because someone forced him or because he choose this layout himself. If the material in the footnote is important to follow the argument it should go in the main text, if it is only a side remark it should go in an excursion at the end of the section or in some appendix.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- I do not dispute the aesthetics argument, which is a matter of taste.  But different genres have different (de facto) rules of the way evidence is presented. In history and law, e.g., long footnotes are often required: the citation style is verbose and there is an expectation that notes, where necessary, include many citations to primary and/or secondary literature; and while the main text must include a translation of (say) a Latin text into a modern language, the footnote itself must include the original Latin. Footnotes become long on that basis alone. (con't)

Comment: ... Perhaps linguistics, too, has conventions that 'necessitate' long footnotes.  The technical question asked here is, in any case, still valid (but requires an MWE).

Comment: OK. We load lots of stuff, I will try and break that down to a MWE within the next days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I found the answer. I have to include the relevant block in

```
{\interfootnotelinepenalty=10%

...

}
```

I did this but just included the paragraph with the footnotes. This was not enough. Once I included a bigger portion of text it worked. I guess the `bigfoot` package does this globally but it intefered with other code we use for getting numbering of examples in footnotes right.